# extending or inferring (PID / UFD) in a Lean class definition

Tags: typeclass, lean

Why is mathlib's definition of UFD this:

```
class unique_factorization_domain (α : Type*) [integral_domain α] :=
(factors : α → multiset α)
(factors_prod : ∀{a : α}, a ≠ 0 → (factors a).prod ~ᵤ a)
(prime_factors : ∀{a : α}, a ≠ 0 → ∀x∈factors a, prime x)
```

(asking for the integral domain structure to be inferred by type class inference) but its definition of PID is this:

```
class principal_ideal_domain (α : Type*) extends integral_domain α :=
(principal : ∀ (S : ideal α), S.is_principal)
```

extending the integral domain structure? What is the difference? Does the old structure command have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression from the [discussion on the Lean chat](https://leanprover-community.github.io/archive/113488general/98892SOstructurequestion.html) is that for subtle reasons related to type class inference it is probably better to extend the class, and so perhaps the definition of UFD needs to be refactored.